# PHPDoc hints for magic methods

Tags: magento2, phpstorm, docblock

I have grown accustomed to the better [PHPDoc](http://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/index.html) coverage of Magento 2, so now it bothers me when the magic getters and setters are highlighted in red in my PhpStorm project files. In classes that I define, I will typically enumerate magic methods using `@method` in the [class PHPDoc](http://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/tags/method.html). However, I am trying to figure out how to hint them on object instances that I don’t control such as event observers. Consider the following example:

```
class Example implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /* @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Page $page */
        $page = $observer->getPage();
    }
}
```

I realize I can use `$observer->getData('page')`, but if I wish to use the magic getter is there a way to prevent PhpStorm from showing the warning:

> Method 'getPage' not found in \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer

Comment: Do you know if there any recommendation against using magic getters/setters because of this? Or did you find a way?

Comment: @Qtax - Nope just living with it. Since this has no functional impact, I think it’s just up to personal preference. There’s definitely no official recommendation against magic methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered a sort of [workaround for this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12583095/1737136). In my IDE settings under *Editor > Inspections > PHP > Undefined > Undefined method* there is an option called “Downgrade severity if __magic methods are present” which when I turn it on dismisses these warnings.
[image: Preference Pane]